# How to lineup scatter plot data point with its respective column in a floating cluster column chart

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-office, charts

[image: Current workings]

This is a pretty rare chart (I haven't seen it used much at all online) so hopefully it doesn't cause issues with my question.

I'm trying to plot the mean for each of the 4 series (columns) in their correct location. So in my screenshot, each symbol should lineup with its respective column. In the end, I'd need a symbol for each column.

Basically each column in each group represents a range. The symbols will then represent the mean/average for this range.

File: https://ufile.io/ostu037b

Comment: Can you please [edit your question](https://superuser.com/posts/1508814/edit) to include sample data. Not everyone will download a file from an unknown source and the question becomes useless once the link goes dead

Comment: Sorry this is my first time doing this, not sure on how to add the source data to SE. Can you tell me how to do this?

Comment: Type in a small, representative sample

Answer (score 0):

You need to use X values that are not just 1, 2, 3, etc. The whole numbers are in the center of the category, so centered between the 2nd and 3rd bars of each category.

In your data, you are using the text categories from the columns as the X values of the scatter series. Since Excel can't plot text as values, it simply uses 1, 2, 3, etc. You will need to generate specific X values for each set of scatter plot Y values in the chart.

To make it easier, change the gap width of one of the column chart series to 100%. Then your X values that correspond to the four columns of each category will be at

category number - 0.3
category number - 0.1
category number + 0.1
category number + 0.3